# Ext.getCmp undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

Though i checked other posts about the same question, they didn't prove to be much helpful.
Below is the code where i am trying to get value of text box but i am repeatedly getting same error.
Is there any alternative method available.

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            padding: '5 5 0 5',
            border: false,
            style: 'background-color: #fff;',

            fieldDefaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                labelAlign: 'left',
                allowBlank: false,
                combineErrors: true,
                msgTarget: 'side'
            },

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'id',
                    fieldLabel: 'id',
                    hidden:true
                },    
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'name',
                    id : 'idname',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    allowBlank:false,
                    blankText:'Name is required'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'accno',
                    maxLength: 16,
                    enforceMaxLength : true,
                    regex: /^.{16}$/,
                    regexText:'Only 16 Digits please',
                    //autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '20', autocomplete: 'off', maxlength: '10'},
                    fieldLabel: 'AccNo'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'trade',
                    fieldLabel: 'Trade'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    name : 'doi',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date Of Insurance',
                    editable: false,
                    value : new Date()
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    name : 'dd',
                    fieldLabel: 'Due Date',
                    editable:false,
                    value : new Date()
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        id:'buttons',
        ui: 'footer',
        items: ['->', {
            iconCls: 'icon-save',
            itemId: 'save',
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function (button) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('You clicked the button');
                var txt = Ext.getCmp('idname').value();
                //var tf = button.up('window').down('#idname');

                Ext.Msg.alert(txt);

            }, 
            action: 'save'
        },{
            iconCls: 'icon-reset',
            text: 'Cancel',
            scope: this,
            handler: this.close
        }]
    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: can you try `getValue()` instead of `value()`, does that correct the issue?

Comment: @weeksdev Tried but still getting same error "TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...) is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [Ext.ComponentQuery.query method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query)

on your button to check

```
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    id:'buttons',
    ui: 'footer',
    items: ['->', {
        iconCls: 'icon-save',
        itemId: 'save',
        text: 'Save', 
        scope:this,
        handler: function (button) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('You clicked the button');
            var txtfield = this.query('#idname');
            var txt = txfield.getValue();
            Ext.Msg.alert(txt);

        }, 
        action: 'save'
    }
```

Comment: Tried your solution but i am getting this error **TypeError: this.query is not a function**
 (My Ext Version is 4.0.0)

Comment: I guess I should of asked, what class are you extending in this?

Comment: Hmmm...it shows in the documentation that this should work. Just to double check are you adding the proper scope to the handler? If you could either print it out on the console or put a break point to see the context of the call